# Include the measurement name in a influxDB select query

Tags: influxdb

I'm trying to construct a influxDB select query that returns feild and tag values but also the name of the measurement the data came from. This is because the query needs to evaluate over multiple measurements. eg:

```
select "foo" from /^(A|B|C)$/ where time > now() - 1h;
```

With the measurements being `A` `B` and `C`. How can i added another select column (say `name`) being the associated measurement name the data came from? eg:

```
foo       name
---------------
bar       A
cat       B
dog       C
mat       A
```

Comment: I don't what your use case is but you can change one of many things and you'd be good. The table name should already be contained in the results, it depends on you how you handle it. You could do 3 different queries and evaluate them separately if you need to handle them differently anyways. You can just put all the data in one measurement and add a tag corresponding to the measurement name that you are using right now, if you handle all the data the same. You could apply a tag that corresponds to the measurement name and select it or group by it, which seems ridiculous ...

Comment: If the table name is already in the results how do i access it programmatically? My use case involves a grafana plugin https://github.com/grafana/worldmap-panel and the formation of click through urls  https://community.hiveeyes.org/t/developing-grafana-worldmap-ng/1824/13 which only have access to field variables accessed in the select query that populates the map. Because my urls have parameters being the measurement names themselves i need these to be returned as field columns.

Comment: Every query returns the series name, you can try it yourself in the influx cli. Try `SHOW measurements` or `SHOW FIELD KEYS ON` and filter the result if you cannot access the raw data from the SELECT queries in grafana.

Comment: @wizzfizz94 in Grafana where you define your queries you can find something called `query inspector` which shows you what the actual query looks like after template variable substitution as well as the results. In the results you can see that the measurement name is present. Weather you have access to that would depend on the Grafana plugin/panel you are using. https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/guides/whats-new-in-v4-5/#query-inspector

Comment: In that case your question would really be about Grafana and the Worldmap plugin rather than Influxdb

Comment: I would suggest that you open another question where you describe your usecase in more detail while providing the context with Grafana and the links.
At this point it is unclear whether you only use the Worldmap panel or you are developing it or something else, where do you define those links, etc.